# Interact with a deployed contract from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-design

Say i have this contract which I have deployed

```
contract A {
        mapping (string => uint) public someMapping;
}
```

Now, can I interact with the data of the deployed contractA in some other contractB i.e in contractB can I get the value of someMapping["someString"]?

I am using Truffle along with Ganache and MetaMask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There's a gotcha, though. Contracts can't yet pass around dynamic-length arguments, so strings won't work. I changed to `bytes32` to make the simple example work.

With that detail out of the way ...

Contract B must have knowledge of contract's A ABI (the function signatures) and it's address.

The easiest method is to include both files in the same source file. Note that you can deploy B only if A is already out there somewhere and you have knowledge of its address.

`B.sol`

```
contract A {
  mapping (bytes32 => uint) public someMapping;
}

contract B {
  A a; // cast "a" as "contract A" defined above

  function B(address addressA) public { // pass address of "A" to the constructor
    a = A(addressA);
  }

  function getAUint(bytes32 key) public view returns(uint) {
    return a.someMapping(key);
  }
}
```

You will obviously have to extend this example to set values in A somehow so the test is a little more interesting.

If the keys really do need to be `strings`, you might consider using `bytes32` hashes of the `strings`. This way, every unique string will create a unique fixed-size key. Stringy keys is almost always a sign of going astray in Solidity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I am getting this error
TypeError: Member "someMapping" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract "A")
I have declared someMapping as public in contract A

Comment: `someMapping()` - with the brackets, because it's a function.